# d3 bar char labels transitions

Tags: d3.js, transition

Im having a bar charts with labels. After data refresh labels are not shown correctly. Not sure what Im doing wrong with newToolTip part.
Labels are not removed and stay on canvas after update data.

Thanks for help.

```
  //function for button click event
         function getValue(myDataArray) {
      document.getElementById('choosenButton').innerHTML = 'chosen data: ' + myDataArray;
      document.getElementById('choosenButton2').innerHTML = 'chosen data: ' + myDataArray;

    //Scales pre chart1 set up for various dataarrays
    var x = d3.scaleBand().domain(d3.range(0, eval(myDataArray).length))
      .range([0, svgWidth])
      .paddingInner(0.05);

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0,d3.max(eval(myDataArray), function(d) {  return (+d.balance)})])
      .range([0, svgHeight]);

    // add the x Axis
    var xAxis = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(eval(myDataArray).map(function(d) { return d.name}))
      .range([0, svgWidth])
      .paddingInner(0.05);

    //add y axis
    var yAxis = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(eval(myDataArray), function(d) {  return (+d.balance)})])
      .range([svgHeight, 0]);


    var bars = myCanvas1.selectAll('rect').data(eval(myDataArray));
    var newToolTip = myCanvas1.selectAll('g').select('.tooltip').data(eval(myDataArray));

      //exit data
      bars.exit()
          .transition()
          .duration(duration1)
          .attr('height', svgHeight - function(d) {  return (+d.balance)})
          .remove();

      //enter new data
      bars.enter()
          .append('rect')
          .style('fill', 'steelblue')
          .on('mouseover',mouseover)
          .on('mouseout', mouseout)
          .attr('x', function(d, i) { return x(i); })
          .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
          .attr('y', function(d) { return (svgHeight - y(+d.balance));})
          .attr('height', function(d) { return y(+d.balance); })
          .merge(bars)
          .transition()
          .duration(duration1) //update
            .attr('x', function(d, i) { return x(i); })
            .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
            .attr('y', function(d) { return (svgHeight - y(+d.balance)); } )
            .attr('height', function(d) { return y(+d.balance); });

      newToolTip.exit()
            .transition()
            .duration(duration1)
            .remove();

      newToolTip.enter()
            .append('text')
            .attr('class', 'tooltip')
            .style('fill', 'red')
            .attr('x', function(d, i) { return x(i); })
            .attr('y', function(d) { return (svgHeight - y(+d.balance) - 20); } )
            .text(function(d) { return +d.balance; });

      newToolTip.attr('x', function(d, i) { return x(i); })
            .style('fill', 'green')
            .attr('y', function(d) { return (svgHeight - y(+d.balance) - 20); } )
            .text(function(d) { return +d.balance; });

  myCanvas1.selectAll('g.yaxis')
            .transition()
            .duration(duration1)
            .call(d3.axisLeft(yAxis));

  myCanvas1.selectAll('g.xaxis')
            .transition()
            .duration(duration1)
              .call(d3.axisBottom(xAxis))
                .selectAll('text')
                .attr('dx', '-2.2em')
                .attr('dy', '-.15em')
                .attr('transform', 'rotate(-65)');

  };

      function mouseover()  {
        d3.select(this).attr('opacity', .5);
      };

      function mouseout() {
        d3.select(this).attr('opacity', 1);
      };
```

Comment: could you please make a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: sorry not very experienced in jsfiddler https://jsfiddle.net/ALdoVentus/b6ksvfct/2/

Comment: quick solution, just select all previous Tooltip and generate new ones `d3.selectAll('.tooltip').remove();`  fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/amani1988/b6ksvfct/3/

Comment: Thanks for answer it is good quick solution. I found problem. I messed up groups now I have:

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code:

```
  var labelsGroup = myCanvas1.append("g")

  var labels = labelsGroup
        .selectAll(".tooltip")
        .data(dataArray1)
        .enter()
        .append('text')
        .attr('class', 'tooltip')
        .attr('x', function(d, i) { return x(i); })
        .attr('y', function(d) { return (svgHeight - y(+d.balance) - 20); } )
        .text(function(d) { return +d.balance; });
```

and after click I upgrade chart with:

```
var newToolTip = labelsGroup.selectAll('.tooltip').data(eval(myDataArray));

      newToolTip.exit()
            .transition()
            .duration(duration1)
            .remove();

     newToolTip.enter()
            .append("text")
            .attr('class', 'tooltip')
            .style('fill', 'red')
            .attr('x', function(d, i) { return x(i); })
            .attr('y', function(d) { return (svgHeight - y(+d.balance) - 20); } )
            .text(function(d) { return +d.balance; })
            .style('opacity', 1);

      newToolTip.attr('x', function(d, i) { return x(i); })
            .style('fill', 'green')
            .attr('y', function(d) { return (svgHeight - y(+d.balance) - 20); } )
            .text(function(d) { return +d.balance; });
```